# Microphone Permission on Firefox in an iFrame not permanent

Tags: javascript, firefox, permissions, sip, voip

I would like to integrate our Web App into an iFrame, but I have some trouble with Firefox. For this I need permanent access to the microphone.

Currently I use:

```html
<iframe allow="microphone" ... />
```

If I try it without an iFrame, I can choose if the browser should remember the answer. But if I try it with an iFrame, the permission is set, but only temporarily. This leads to the problem that our users are asked every time a call is incoming with sip.js.

How can I get permanent access to the microphone in an iFrame? ( FIREFOX )

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the option to persist the permission in a cross-domain `iframe` [has been removed](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-25/#CVE-2019-11748), as a security update in version 69.